# How to pass all the local variables in one asp.net controller to view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

In asp.net mvc3, I've got a few local variables in one of the controller, is there any neat way to pass all these variables to view? Something like "locals()" in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to explicitly pass them to the view - using a view model.

Comment: @Darin - fair enough... pit of success widened ;)